# Multi-file upload into grid

Tags: file-uploads, grid

I've seen hints that the native Grid Fieldtype allows multi-file uploads but I can't find that feature.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/jf-multi-file-field says "the new ‘Grid’ field does everything this add-on does" and one of the comments on http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/introducing-grid-new-in-expressionengine-2.7 seems to indicate the same.

but I must be missing something. can someone explain how I can upload multiple images into the grid?

Comment: You upload files to individual cells in your grid. Much like you would put them into an excel spreadsheet

http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/introducing-grid-new-in-expressionengine-2.7

Comment: that's the same link that I referenced. 
so there is no multi-file upload option then? as in: upload multiple files at once ( similar to how the matrix multi-file upload plugin would allow it).

Comment: That's correct. Can @JohnathanWaters can you post your answer as an answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not natively upload all the files at once with grid. But you can individually select them for each cell in the grid

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't apply to Grid, so I'm just leaving this here as it's the most relevant q/a I found to bring it up. I wanted to be able to select multiple files in a single cell. Since the only obvious multi upload was [P&T's Matrix Multi Upload](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix-multi-upload) (it uploads whatever files you pick, then generates a row in Matrix for each file, as opposed to a new File fieldtype that allows multiple file selection) basically I'll upload all the files in advance (dummy field, or dummy entry, or same entry then refresh, whatever) and use a [MX Select Plus](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-select)($) field that yields a dropdown based on your own sql query (for me it was a list of specific filetypes).

Haven't used in templating yet but as far as control panel GUI goes that's the combination I've got going.